# Random colours for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make each element within a container a different background colour selected randomly from an array. How do I get the script to run separately for each new element?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#ff0000","#ff00ff","#00ff00"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
  $('.resource-cards > div').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resource-cards">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop thru each div and assign a random color.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.resource-cards > div').each(function() {
    var colors = ["#ff0000", "#ff00ff", "#00ff00"];
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resource-cards">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To make this work for each element individually you need to loop over the `div` elements and generate a random number for each one, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ["#ff0000", "#ff00ff", "#00ff00"];

  $('.resource-cards > div').each(function() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    $(this).css("background-color", colors[rand]);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resource-cards">
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
  <div>some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Different background color for container that selected randomly from an array.

Use looping concept.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.resource-cards > div').each(function() {
    var colorsArray = ["#338DFF","#ff0000", "#ff00ff", "#00ff00","#FF5733"];
    var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorsArray.length);
    $(this).css("background-color", colorsArray[randnum]);
  });
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="resource-cards">
  <div>DIV 1</div>
  <div>DIV 2</div>
  <div>DIV 3</div>
  <div>DIV 4</div>
  <div>DIV 5</div>
</div>
```